# Dracena Happy Plant mould on Trunk

Tags: plant-care, indoors

We bought home a Dracena plant about two months ago, it has been watered once since we have had it. We live in Melbourne Australia, so we are now in Winter. It is in a sunlit room in a corner out of direct sun. Noticed what seems to look like Green mould/moss on the trunks enter image description here as well has brown and yellow tips on leaves and some on the actual leaves. I have just now place it near a window hoping it will help the trunks. What are we doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Lichen , I don't have any on house plants but is is common  on local trees and bare wood . It is not parasitic.